# MySQL が起動できません（パスワードが要求される）

Tags: mysql

MySQL を起動しようとしてみたろころ、
パスワードが要求されました。
一度もパスワードは設定したことがありません。

MySQLを使いたいのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか？

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.34, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

```
$ service mysqld stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop mysqld.service
Failed to stop mysqld.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status mysqld.service' for details.
```

```
$ mysql.server start
-bash: mysql.server: command not found
$ /etc/init.d/mysqld start
-bash: /etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory
```

インストールされてないような感じのエラーが出ます。

Comment: コマンドをみるとmysqlを起動しているものがありませんが、起動したときのエラー情報も質問に追記してください

Comment: mysqlのサービスがないということはインストールになにか間違いがあった可能性がありますね。ご自身が行ったmysqlのインストール手順も追記で教えてください。